# BigQuery: Pageviews, Sessions, Users by differents sources, medium, campaigns

Tags: google-bigquery

What is the query for Pageviews, Sessions, Users  by differents sources, medium, campaigns?

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry,

In the future you should share what you have tried, why it is not working and specifically where you need help.  I am guessing your down votes are because of the lack of effort on your end.

Google has great documentation on how to use the Google Analytics Big Query data schema which can be found here: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en

Additionally Google has great documentation on their legacy and standard SQL syntax for working with and extracting data in BigQuery which can be found here:

Standard SQL: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/

Legacy SQL: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql

If you haven't already, you should read and understand the documentation.  You may also want to pick up a book on SQL.

Regardless, I've been in your position.  Below is some SQL that will get you started.  There are times where an analyst has to make a decision on how to extract and handle data.  The SQL below will get you started but you may need to tweak the code to meet your needs.  Remember to replace the 'your table here' text with the actual table you are trying to query.

```
#standardsQL
SELECT 
trafficSource.source AS source,
trafficSource.medium AS medium,
trafficSource.campaign AS campaign, 
SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageviews,
SUM(totals.visits) AS sessions,
COUNT(DISTINCT fullVisitorId) AS users
FROM `your table here`
GROUP BY
source,
medium,
campaign
```

Good Luck!